# Is there a layout in android studio that is able to infinitely expand in every direction?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm relatively new to coding, especially with android(xml,java). 
I had an idea for an app but it appears that it requires a layout that I can't seem to find.
So what I'd need is a layout that starts out with the screen size and dynamically expands in the given direction as the user drags along the screen.

In addition to that I want to be able to create objects(textview, imageview) at any given point on the layout which can also overlap as they can in Absolute- or RelativeLayout. 
 Those objects should dynamically be loaded and destroyed as they move in and out of view.
So I don't know if there's anything like this.
 I've searched for quite a bit but only found layouts that were able to either scroll horizontally or vertically.
If anybody got an idea how I could possibly realize such a view, please let me know!

Best regards, BlackCert

Comment: Your description does not sound like a usable interface, can you be more specific of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: read about https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html  & 
 https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

Comment: @JonasKöritz Hey, so the basic idea is to create an app very similar to the homepage yourworldoftext. But instead of only having text in there, I want to be able to store text, images, videos etc.. Unlike yourworldoftext it should not be one huge textview where everyone can create/delete everything they want but rather an at first blank view on which objects(textview, imageview) can be created if the user has given privileges.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, doing everything manually through OpenGL seems appropriate. You could render only the items that are visible and dont have to mess with Android getting painfully slow when dealing with huge layouts. Set-Up a 2D scene and write rendering code for each kind of item you want to display.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answers Jonas and @Tauqir.